# Is it possible to make a Bing Maps TileLayer clickable?

Tags: event-handling, addeventlistener, bing-maps

There are [Data Layer Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750277.aspx) with which you can add e.g. click events to the [Layer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712656.aspx). How can I add event handlers to the [TileLayer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712660.aspx)?

In the [WMS Tile Layer Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt762880.aspx) I wish I could add the following lines of code:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(NOAAWeatherRadar, 'click', function() { 
  // add infobox
});
```

Is this realizable or do you know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tile layers do not have mouse events in any map control. Tile layers cover the complete surface of the map. If you want a mouse event simply add an event to the map itself. If you want to be able to detect a mouse event on a shape drawn in the tile layer, then you will need to do some server side processing to test for intersection against the raw data.